# Django polymorphic models with unique_together

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I have these this base model:

```
class Trackable(PolymorphicModel):
    uuid = UUIDField(unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And a child model extends it:

```
class Like(Trackable):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, related_name='likes')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['content', 'created_by']
```

When I run migration, it complains about:

```
django.db.models.fields.FieldDoesNotExist: Like has no field named u'created_by'
```

Comment: Do you want `Trackable` to be its own table, related to `Like` by a foreign key? If not, use [`abstract=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and your `unique_together` will work as expected. If so, you won't be able to enforce that constraint with `unique_together`.

Comment: I am not sure if adding that will work properly using https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic since I don't see it mentions about using abstract=True in base models.

Comment: I glanced at that project and it looks like it's designed for `abstract=False` inheritance. In which case you're talking about two different tables, making it impossible to use `unique_together` that way. Note that `abstract=True` will provide better performance and allow the unique constraint, so think about whether you really need to use multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks @KevinChristopherHenry I need to use the ploymorphic model because it casts types for me automatically, also multi-table allows me to get query the base model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I handled this problem.  Bear in mind that I use PostGres as my database and I do not know if the same problems occur with other databases (though I guess that they do).

Unique together constraints can only be applied to a single table or view in PostGres.  This means that out of the box Django/Django-polymorphic cannot express database-enforced unique constraints on a combination of fields that are in both a parent table and a child table of Django models in an inheritance hierarchy.

If you really want database enforced unique constraints on these fields, you can do one of these two things:

1. copy any parent-model fields that are involved in the unique constraint into the child's table, and express the unique constraint on the child's fields and the fields copied from the parent, or
2. create a view on the child that includes both the fields from the parent and those from the child, and express the unique constraint on this view.

You will have to either do this manually, or develop your own framework for inserting/altering/deleting these constraints automatically.

Comment: I believe you [can't copy parent-model fields in inheriting models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) so option 1 doesn't work.

Comment: You can't copy the parent fields such that they have the same fieldname in the child model in Django - but you can copy them to a new fieldname in the child model.  I think you can then setup database triggers to take care of keeping the copied fields in sync.  The constraint is then expressed on the copied field in the child model as explained above.  (I'm not saying this pretty!  But it is possible)

Comment: Oh I see the logic there that would indeed work. Ultimately if django_polymorphic was set up to work with abstract base models it would work without hacking it together but there doesn't seem to be any plans to support that.