# Django unique_together on model parent class fields

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I want to generalize my workflow with models where presented GenericForeignKey fields.

So I create parent class GFKModel:

```
class GFKModel(models.Model):
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_id')
```

Then I inherit it:

```
class Question(GFKModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('author', 'target_content_type', 'target_id')
```

I need to add unique_together constraint on both 'author', 'target_content_type' and 'target_id', but I can't do that due to migration error:

```
qna.Question: (models.E016) 'unique_together' refers to field 'target_content_type' which is not local to model 'Question'.
HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've missed declaration of GFKModel as 'abstract' class:

```
class GFKModel(models.Model):
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of Alex T works for abstract base models

If however you use a concrete base model you [cannot use unique_together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799949/django-polymorphic-models-with-unique-together)

More on different polymorphism types in Django:

https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/#concrete-base-model

Comment: If you are using a concrete class as a parent django creates a table with a pointer in the database, that's why you cannot use the unique together, however you can create an abstract parent and abstract child and inherit to parent and child concrete classes.

Comment: You could edit this answer or create a new one that describes what you mean with ideally an example.