# Django Model Constraint Condition Using Field From Inherited Class - Is It Possible?

Tags: django, django-models, django-constraints

I'd like to use a field from a parent class as a constraint condition in a child class.

**models.py**

```
class ParentClass(object):
    ...
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    ...
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(price__isnull=True) & Q(is_public=True), # <- here
                name='price_exists_check',
            )
        ]
```

When I attempt to migrate, I see this error in my terminal:

```
myapp.ChildClass: (models.E016) 'constraints' refers to field 'is_public'
  which is not local to model 'ChildClass'.
  HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
```

It's obvious why I am seeing this error (`is_public` field lives in `ParentClass`). My question is, is it simply not possible then, or can I refactor something?

**What is my end-goal?**

To not let an instance of `ChildClass` `is_pulic` change to `True` if the `price` is `null`. I'd like to enforce this at the database level.

Is there a way and if so, what needs to change?

Comment: Does marking the parent as an abstract class help? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36824386/530160 Or do you need the parent class to be a concrete class?

Comment: I do need the parent class to be a concrete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is it simply not possible then, or can I refactor something?

I tracked down the [original commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/0bcc92c6917738caa2f08ec16d26fad62974fb47) which introduced the error message you're seeing, and the [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22356) it was fixing. The documentation on [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) is also helpful for understanding this.

Here's how I understand the issue:

If you create a Django model which inherits from another model, and that model is not abstract, then Django creates a foreign key to the parent table, rather than repeat all of the fields from the parent model in the child table. So when you create a ChildClass object, that creates both a row in the ChildClass table *and* the ParentClass table.

You can't create a CHECK constraint which references multiple tables. (As far as I know.) Therefore, Django forbids you from creating this constraint.

Therefore, you have the following options:

1. **Enforce it at the ORM layer**. In the clean() method, check if your constraint is satisfied. ([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean).) This won't prevent violation of the constraint if a non-Django program modifies the database.
2. **Make the parent class abstract**. You've already said this is not workable.
3. **Make a third class, which both inherit from**. Create a base class like this:

   ```
               -------------
               | BaseClass |
               -------------
               |           |
               V           V
   ---------------       --------------
   | ParentClass |       | ChildClass |
   ---------------       --------------
   ```

   Make the BaseClass abstract, and the ParentClass and ChildClass concrete. This allows you to use a constraint, because the ChildClass data is inside just one table now.